# SharePoint 2013 - JavaScript get URL from List

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-2013

I am using the below JavaScript code to get the title of all lists in SharePoint 2013. How can i adapt this to return the URL of each list as well?

I've tired this but it doesn't work:

```
    //listUrl   = oList.get_url();
    //console.log(listUrl);
```

Code:

```
function retrieveAllListProperties() {
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext('/StrategicProjectOffice');
    var oWebsite = clientContext.get_web();
    this.collList = oWebsite.get_lists();
    clientContext.load(collList);

    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
        Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded)
    );
}

function onQuerySucceeded() {
    var listTitle = '';
    var listEnumerator = collList.getEnumerator();
    while (listEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        var oList = listEnumerator.get_current();
        listTitle = oList.get_title();
        //listUrl   = oList.get_url();
        //console.log(listUrl);
        if (listTitle.indexOf("SPO") >= 0) {
            getItemsFromView(listTitle, "All Tasks");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

List Url could be retrieved via [`SPList.RootFolder` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splist.rootfolder.aspx), in your example the line:

```
clientContext.load(collList);
```

needs to be replaced with

```
clientContext.load(collList,'Include(RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl)');
```

which tells to construct a query to return `RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl` property of `List` object.

Example

Here is my version which retrieves lists and prints its url:

```
var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var web = ctx.get_web();
var lists = web.get_lists();
ctx.load(lists,'Include(RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl)');
ctx.executeQueryAsync(
   function () {
     for(var i = 0; i < lists.get_count(); i++){
        var list = lists.getItemAtIndex(i);
        var listUrl = list.get_rootFolder().get_serverRelativeUrl();
        console.log(listUrl);
     }
   },
   function(sender,args){
      console.log(args.get_message());
   }
);
```